# Wrap all jQuery functions into a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to wrap all of `jQuery's` DOM functions for a js class, but have those functions only deal with a single property of that class.

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.$wrapper = $('<div>wrapper</div>')
  }
}

var f = new Foo();

// have to call this
f.$wrapper.appendTo($('body'));
// want to call this
f.appendTo($('body'));
```

I could do this manually, which would take eons, by creating a same-named method for each jQuery method and simply always apply it to `this.$wrapper`. But I wonder if there is a simpler way to do this.

https://jsfiddle.net/gy9tLyk2/

Comment: Is this client-side scripting? If so, `class` won't be supported on several major browsers because it's from ECMAScript 6.

Comment: That sorta defeats the entire point of what you're doing? If you still want to call `f.appendTo` directly just do `var f = $(...)` and drop the class, as you would have to set `f` to be equal to the wrapped jQuery element returned anyway.

Comment: Read some examples of OOJS (object oriented javascript)

Comment: @4castle I use babel to transpile.

Comment: @adeneo Maybe this is just a silly idea.

Comment: Seems like a lot of extra work.... and is a solution looking for a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just extend `jQuery.fn.init` and use a `super` call:

```js
class Foo extends jQuery.fn.init {
  constructor() {
    super('<div>wrapper</div>');
  }
}
Foo.prototype.constructor = jQuery;
new Foo().appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note I replace `Foo.prototype.constructor` because jQuery will access the `constructor` property of the instance and call it. But ES6 classes like `Foo` are not callable, and jQuery is not supposed to call `Foo`.

Not sure if babel will be able to transpile correctly, here is the ES5 code:

```js
function Foo() {
  this.init('<div>wrapper</div>');
}
Foo.prototype = Object.create(jQuery.fn);
new Foo().appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is using ES2015 proxies, i.e. the `Proxy` constructor.

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.$wrapper = $('<div>wrapper</div>');
    return new Proxy(this, {
        get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
         if ( target.hasOwnProperty(prop) ) {
           return target[prop];
         }
         return function() {
           let ret = target.$wrapper[prop](...arguments);
           if ( ret !== target.$wrapper ) return ret;
           return receiver;
         }
      }
    });
  }
}

var f = new Foo();
var a = f.appendTo($('body')).text('changed').prop('tagName');
```

But it's not recommended for several reasons:

1. Browser support
2. Proxies are slow
3. jQuery has getters and setters and creating a proxy handler than handles all the jQuery and the class methods can be tricky.

Comment: Proxies are difficult to understand. Is it essentially cloning an object and overriding one of it's properties?

Comment: @Tester232323 No, it doesn't clone the object, it wraps the object and controls the _behavior_ of it. Just like magic methods of PHP. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy